# Problems exporting a React app as a npm module that contains a SVG picture

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I have a React application created with `create-react-app`. I have built and published it as a `npm` module. Everything works fine, I can use the components I have exported etc. The one problem I'm having is that pictures `(SVGs)` in my case, won't be displayed in the application that have imported that module.

The picture below shows the folder structure of the project being exported and published as a npm module.

[image: Folder structure in the project being exported as npm module]

The picture below shows the folder structure of the imported module while being used in a project.

[image]

The picture below shows the component I export.

[image]

The picture below shows the compiled exported component.

[image]

The picture below shows the component above being used in the project that imports the module.

[image]

The pictures below show the app that imports the module failing to render the picture.

[image]

[image]

Do you guys have any idea of why the picture is not loading properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because of wrong importing `SVG` - 
per [docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files#adding-svgs) you need to import `SVG` like:

```
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from './udilia-logo.svg';
```

also it may be due wrong version of `react-create-app`

> this feature is available with react-scripts@2.0.0 and higher, and react@16.3.0 and higher.